# Select-Object -Unique and MemberTypes

Tags: powershell, member, select-object

As part of a larger script i'm making a refrencelist of servernames which should contain all servers in our infrastructure. To do this i have 4 arrays with servernames sourced from diffrent systems (AD, SQL etc) which i planned to join together using:

```
$Refrencelist = $var1.Name + $var2.Name + $var3.Name + $var4.Name | Select-Object -Unique
```

Altough this mostly does the job i'm still seeing some duplicates in the resultning list and from what i can gather it's because the MemberType of the .Name property in the SQL $var  is Property while the MemberType of Name in the other varibales is NoteProperty.

Is this what's causing the duplicates? If so, how do i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine the objects to an array and use `-Unique` on the `name` Property:

```
$referenceList = @($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
$uniqueList = $referenceList | select -Unique {$_.Name}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.

That didn´t work unfortently the result is this which doesnt seem to be in a format i can work with for further filtering and export.  

$_.Name
-------
{server105, server23, server145, server103...}
{server12, server11, server12, server13...}
{server7, server8, server9, server10...}

Sorry for not fornatting properly, can´t get it to recognise the above lines as code for some reason.